# Change a Variable's Name in Matlab's Workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a problem that has more than likely been asked before but I have yet to find a solution that works for me.

I would like to know if it's possible to change the name of variable within a workspace in Matlab?

The need for this is a follows,

I have a small section of code that imports over 60's columns of data from Excel into Matlab, each column has over 10,000 rows in, so a fair amount of data. Row 1 of each column is the variable, i.e. R1C1 = "Time from X to Z" I would like to know if its possible for Matlab to create a Variable called "Time_from_X_to_Z"  then store all the data in that Variable from the excel sheet. I am able to store all the data in separate variables, I just need a bit of help naming the variable.

I would like to name the variables like so, as when I come to re-use the code the order of the column may change from time to time, hence why I can't just let Variable1 = Varibale1 etc.

Here is some of the code I have tried from my research.

```
VariableName = txt(1,i);
VariableName = num2str(cell2mat(VariableName));

VariableName = Variable 
clear Variable
```

This was my most successful one but is nowhere near what I expected it to be.

I hope that all makes sense.

Thanks for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: What you are triying to do, dynamic variables, is a very very bad programming practice that will only lead to very bad headches when you want to do further things with the code. Use proper variables, like tables, cell arrays or matrices.

Comment: Ohh yeah I understand that it will be messy but I currently can't think of another method that will work in theory

Comment: Could you provide a complete code along with the first couple of lines from your data set?

Comment: "I would like to name the variables like so, as when I come to re-use the code the order of the column may change from time to time..." That's what array indices are for, to enforce ordering of the elements. Your data belongs in an array. If the data you're reading is of varying sizes, use a cell array or struct array.

Comment: If you use a function like `readtable` then MATLAB will handle the column / row names for you, and you can refer to the data by column or row names in a single table. This way you don't need many variables with unknown names floating around in your workspace, with all the headaches that brings along...